# Each time a div is clicked I want that div to hold a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django

Here is what my Month component looks like essentially  a grid with days as columns and hours of the days as rows

```html
import React from "react";

export function Month() {
  const currentDate = new Date();
  const days = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    const day = new Date(currentDate);
    day.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + i);
    days.push(day);
  }

  return (
    <div className="container justify-content-center ">
      <div className="row ">
        <div className="col-md-1">hour</div>
        <div className="col ">
          <strong>
            {new Date().toLocaleDateString("en-US", { weekday: "long" })}
          </strong>{" "}
        </div>
        <div className="col">
          <strong>
            {days[1].toLocaleDateString("en-US", { weekday: "long" })}
          </strong>
        </div>
        <div className="col">
          <strong>
            {days[2].toLocaleDateString("en-US", { weekday: "long" })}
          </strong>
        </div>
        <div className="col">
          <strong>
            {days[3].toLocaleDateString("en-US", { weekday: "long" })}
          </strong>
        </div>
        <div className="col">
          <strong>
            {days[4].toLocaleDateString("en-US", { weekday: "long" })}
          </strong>
        </div>
        <div className="col">
          <strong>
            {days[5].toLocaleDateString("en-US", { weekday: "long" })}
          </strong>
        </div>
        <div className="col">
          <strong>
            {days[6].toLocaleDateString("en-US", { weekday: "long" })}
          </strong>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-1">7:00</div>
        {days.map((day, index) => (
          <div className="col pb-5 bg-light border border-dark" key={index}>
            {day.toLocaleDateString()}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-1 d-flex">8:00</div>
        <div
          className="col pb-5 bg-light border border-dark"
          style={{ height: "73.33px" }}
        ></div>
        <div
          className="col pb-5 bg-light border border-dark"
          style={{ height: "73.33px" }}
        ></div>
        <div
          className="col pb-5 bg-light border border-dark"
          style={{ height: "73.33px" }}
        ></div>
        <div
          className="col pb-5 bg-light border border-dark"
          style={{ height: "73.33px" }}
        ></div>
        <div
          className="col pb-5 bg-light border border-dark"
          style={{ height: "73.33px" }}
        ></div>
        <div
          className="col pb-5 bg-light border border-dark"
          style={{ height: "73.33px" }}
        ></div>
        <div
          className="col pb-5 bg-light border border-dark"
          style={{ height: "73.33px" }}
        ></div>
      </div>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-1 d-flex">9:00</div>
        <div
          className="col pb-5 bg-light border border-dark"
          style={{ height: "73.33px" }}
        ></div>
        <div
          className="col pb-5 bg-light border border-dark"
          style={{ height: "73.33px" }}
        ></div>
        <div
          className="col pb-5 bg-light border border-dark"
          style={{ height: "73.33px" }}
        ></div>
        <div
          className="col pb-5 bg-light border border-dark"
          style={{ height: "73.33px" }}
        ></div>
        <div
          className="col pb-5 bg-light border border-dark"
          style={{ height: "73.33px" }}
        ></div>
        <div
          className="col pb-5 bg-light border border-dark"
          style={{ height: "73.33px" }}
        ></div>
        <div
          className="col pb-5 bg-light border border-dark"
          style={{ height: "73.33px" }}
        ></div>
      </div>
```

what I want is that each time I create a task I want that specific task to be displayed in the exact position in my month grid that It was clicked here is my TaskFormPage

```html
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { createTask } from "../api/task.api";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export function TaskFormPage() {
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const onSubmit = handleSubmit(async (data) => {
    await createTask(data);
    navigate("/tasks");
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="title"
          {...register("title", { required: true })}
          name="title"
        />
        <textarea
          rows="3"
          placeholder="description"
          {...register("description", { required: true })}
          name="description"
        ></textarea>
        <input
          type="datetime-local"
          placeholder="date"
          {...register("date", { required: true })}
        />
        <button>Create Task</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Right now I am  only deploying my taskcards in some divs making some get request to the Django rest API

```html
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { getTasks } from "../api/task.api";
import { TaskCard } from "./TaskCard";

export function TaskLists() {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function loadTasks() {
      const res = await getTasks();
      console.log(res.data);
      setTasks(res.data);
    }
    loadTasks();
  }, []);

  const removeTask = (id) => {
    setTasks(tasks.filter((task) => task.id !== id));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {tasks.map((task) => (
        <TaskCard key={task.id} task={task} onDelete={removeTask} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I was thinking of passing a list of TaskCard components as a prompt to my Month component but how I would handle the position of each card to be the same as the position it was clicked?

[image]

Comment: I didn't exactly know what Month component is. What are 7:00, 8.00 ,dates for one row....  ?.  Please add picture of that component for understanding it. I don't have classes that are used in it component.

Comment: 7:00 and 8:00 are just rows with the hours of the day like Google calendar

Comment: Please add photo of Month component and your design. Do you mean the tasks are  only specified by month? or day?

Comment: @J.Porter see the last edit including image at the bottom of the question, task are specified for an hour of the day

Comment: So you mean, only a week info is visible in month component?

Comment: @J.Porter for now yes, later I will include other weeks

Comment: Every tasks must be in suitable div sorted by date? or definitely hour? If so, in 7:00 it's not empty, where task should go?

Comment: if I clicked in the div the task should go to that div

Comment: so thats by day and hour

Comment: I have simplify each div as follows:  <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-1 d-flex">8:00</div>
        <Daycard />
        <Daycard />
        <Daycard />
        <Daycard />
        <Daycard />
        <Daycard />
        <Daycard />
      </div>